# Very Goth film, secret order of monster hunters, girl takes cup out of picture

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a film where the heroine discovers that her mother belonged to a secret, presumably hereditary, group of monster hunters.  She gets taken to their underground headquarters, which includes an impressive sort of library place with stone pillars.  The film was too Goth for words, more the wispy fantasy style of Goth than the leather jacket kind.

At one point, the heroine and a boy and possibly others were in a lair of vampires, there were a lot of dangling chains in it.  Before they managed to escape, the boy got bitten, and later he's recovering in bed back in the hunters' HQ and she visits him, and he mysteriously doesn't need his glasses any more, and you think "Aha"... but then it's never mentioned again.

The heroine discovers that she's inherited her mother's ability to put real objects into pictures and take them out again.  She takes out a cup or something that her mother had left in a book.  Later, she discovers a magical object that the hunters need to defeat some villain, hidden in a picture, presumably by her mother.  But they've been lying to her about things and she refuses to hand it over until they start telling her the truth, and she runs away.

At some point she discovers her mother, who's in some kind of magical coma, and tries to wake her up, but doesn't manage it.

It ended up with her and a boy riding away together on a motorbike, and there was possibly an air of a sequel being intended, but I'm not sure.

Anyone know the name of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like ***[The Mortal Instruments: City of Bones](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1538403/)*** (2013).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mortal_Instruments:_City_of_Bones):

> *The Mortal Instruments: City of Bones* is a 2013 urban fantasy film based on the first book of *The Mortal Instruments* series by Cassandra Clare. It was directed by Harald Zwart, with a script written by Jessica Postigo. The film stars Lily Collins as Clary Fray, a teenager from New York City who meets a group of Nephilim known as the Shadowhunters while also discovering her own heritage and her family history. The cast also include Jamie Campbell Bower, Robert Sheehan, Kevin Zegers, Lena Headey, Kevin Durand, Aidan Turner, Jemima West, Godfrey Gao, C. C. H. Pounder, Jared Harris, and Jonathan Rhys Meyers.

From IMDB:

> When her mother disappears, Clary Fray learns that she descends from a line of warriors who protect our world from demons. She joins forces with others like her and heads into a dangerous alternate New York called the Shadow World.

The protagonist, Clary Fray, learns that her mother was a one of a number of half-human, half-angel demon slayers, known as Shadowhunters.

At around the [33:37](https://youtu.be/iGMSMxvsEKc?t=2017) mark, she enters the library of the Shadowhunter Institute, which has several tall pillars, much as you described.

At around the [49:49](https://youtu.be/iGMSMxvsEKc?t=2017) mark, she and some of the Shadowhunters break into a vampires' lair, and rescue a Shadowhunter who's bound by, and hanging from, chains.

At around the [1:13:39](https://youtu.be/iGMSMxvsEKc?t=4419) mark, she discovers she can place a teacup within the page of a book, and then pull it back out again. Apparently, her mother was the only other person who could do this.

At around the [1:45:39](https://youtu.be/iGMSMxvsEKc?t=6339) mark, she finds her mother in a coma-like state, and her mother remains in this state for the rest of the film.

In the closing scene, at around the [2:01:42](https://youtu.be/iGMSMxvsEKc?t=7302) mark, she hops on a motorcycle with a young, male Shadowhunter, and they ride off together.

The Wikipedia page mentions a cancelled sequel called *[The Mortal Instruments: City of Ashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mortal_Instruments:_City_of_Ashes_(unproduced_film))*, which was set to be released in 2014.

Comment: This is the one, thanks, and a very thorough answer!  No mistaking that stargate-type thing, for one thing (I'm surprised I forgot to put *that* in the question).  I've heard of the *Mortal Instruments* books, at least the title, so I'm surprised I didn't remember that - I'd had a vague idea that the film had a one-word title, for some reason, must have mixed it up with something!

Comment: “she discovers she can place a teacup within the page of a book, and then pull it back out again” — the best superpower! No more struggling to fit all your teacups into limited cupboard space!

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - I don't have that problem. I designed my cupboards so that they're bigger on the inside. Also, my bedroom wardrobe contains a portal to Narnia, which is surprisingly handy for storage purposes.